# old topic, but still can't find the clue

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have three 'select', so after the first and second are selected, I would use ajax to populate the third one depending on the first and second.

I can see the first alert called, then nothing further. Where is the problem? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
$('.second').on('change', function(){

if($(".first").val() == "Users" && $(this).val() == "add"){


            alert("call ajax");

            $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url: url,
                    data: params,
                    success: function(response) {
                            alert("succ ajax");
                            ....
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                            alert("fail ajax");
                            ...
                    },
            });

            alert("ajax fin");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I forgot the definition for 'params' which I copied from my another part of code. I saw the error in the debugger.

Shame on myself. Sorry guys.